# Throwing HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net

When I build the application,its running fine but when I publish the website its saying

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Its not saying in which file or line the error is.And when I browse it through IIS its showing

> "The configuration section 'compilation' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration".

I have tried many things like changing application pool,setting `custom error=off`,removing `authentication mode=windows` tag etc still the site is not getting published.
Here is my **web.config**.Thanks for any help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="request_images" value="\\172.16.0.12\\d$\DealerImages\\"/>
    <add key="etreq" value="http://172.16.0.12/et"/>
    <add key="failcnt" value="5"/>
    <add key="ValidPwdDays" value="45"/>
    <add key="pushsms.Service1" value="http://www.kar.nic.in/karsms/smssend/Service1.asmx"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleVATepayment" connectionString="provider = ORAOLEDB.oracle.1;user ID=efvat;password=ef$v1a2t3;trusted connection=true;data source = efvat12" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
    <add name="OracleMinact" connectionString="provider = ORAOLEDB.oracle.1;user ID=pttest;password=pt1234;trusted connection=true;data source = efvat12" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha "/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" theme="Default" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <!--<add value="firsthome.aspx"/>-->
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure the hosting supports .NET 4.0?

Comment: When do you exactly get the null reference error? Does it happen with all pages? A static HTML works? Try removing part of your site to find what's causing this.